# Exception Wrapping

Tags: java, exception, word-wrap

Can any one suggest me that wrapping up data to exception is a good practice in Java?

Here is what I am planning to do: I would like to wrap certain details in exception and want to access those when ever exception occurs.

```
class MyCustomException extends Exception{

private String id;
private String name;

public MyExcpetion(String id, String name){
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
}

public String getId(){ return this.id; }
public String getName() { return this.name }

}
```

Regards,
Sandy..

Comment: Where would you be using the exception-- could you add some more context?

Comment: Mick,
I would to redirect to some page based on the exception what i receive. As part of redirection it requires some additional parameter.

Comment: What I meant was that whether you always throw  `MyCustomException` when some other exception is caught in your  code. If so, I would modify the constructor into `public MyCustomException(Throwable cause, String id, String name) { super(cause); /*...*/ }` so that the stack trace of the original cause is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Not a bad idea. Recommend you also observe the interface of Exception, so be sure to pass to the super class an error message and any exception you may have caught. This object will then be usable both as a normal Exception (checked I presume) and also as your custom type (for smarter exception handlers) which can immediately use those extra properties.

The real question, though, is how your exception handler will be better through having those properties. If they enable recovery or better error reporting, then that's great. If not, then do the simplest thing that can possibly work.

Comment: Thanks for your input Ashley.